# Unable to connect to Amazon S3 using python / boto - proxy connection issues

Tags: python, amazon-s3, proxy, boto

I have a script that should connect to S3, find a particular bucket and then get_contents_to_filename for each new key in that bucket

```
conn = S3Connection(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, debug=1,calling_format=ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat())
bucket = Bucket(conn, 'bucket_name_here')
```

This is the loop to get the keys within the bucket

```
        # Loop through each key for each hour of the day
        for idx, key in enumerate(bucket.list(PATH)):

            logger2.info('Key: %s' % str(key))

            # Create new filename for output - appid_yyyy_mm_dd_hh

            file_name = app_id + dt.strftime("%Y_%m_%d") + "_" + str(idx) + '.log.gz'
            current_file = dateutil.parser.parse(key.last_modified[:19])

            # print current time and last observer time
            logger3.info('Current File Datetime:'+ ' ' + str(current_file) + '       ' +
                             'Last Modified Datetime:' + ' ' + str(max_file_datetime))

            if current_file <= max_file_datetime:
                    logger.info('skipping file: ' + str(key.name))
            else:
                try:
                    logger.info('downloading file' + str(key.name))
                    key.get_contents_to_filename(outlocation + file_name,cb=mycb,num_cb=5)
                except Exception, e:
                    logger.error('Unable to download Key contents to file: %s' %str(e))
```

I'm running this code from behind my company's proxy - currently using cntlm to try bypass it but I keep getting errors at the get_contents_to_filename due to connection issues

This are the errors I get:

socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a per
iod of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Also when I turn on debugging this is the output:

```
     2015-07-30 19:13:52,427 foo [DEBUG]:Using access key provided by 

client.
2015-07-30 19:13:52,427 foo [DEBUG]:Using secret key provided by client.
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:path=/------string------/
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:auth_path=/------string------/
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:path=/------string------/?prefix-------------------------
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:auth_path=/------string------/?prefix-------------------------
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Method: GET
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Path: /------string------/?prefix-------------------------
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Data:
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Headers: {}
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Host: s3.amazonaws.com
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Port: 443
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:Params: {}
2015-07-30 19:13:52,489 foo [DEBUG]:establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'port': 443, 'timeout'
: 70}
2015-07-30 19:13:52,941 foo [DEBUG]:Token: None
2015-07-30 19:13:52,941 foo [DEBUG]:StringToSign:
GET


Thu, 30 Jul 2015 18:13:52 GMT
/exports.localytics/
2015-07-30 19:13:52,941 foo [DEBUG]:Signature:
AWS ---------------string---------------=
2015-07-30 19:13:52,941 foo [DEBUG]:Final headers: {'Date': 'Thu, 30 Jul 2015 18:13:52 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Aut
horization': u'-----string_here----------', 'User-Agent': 'Boto/2.38.0 Python/2.7.10 Windows/
8'}
2015-07-30 19:14:13,999 foo [DEBUG]:encountered error exception, reconnecting
2015-07-30 19:14:13,999 foo [DEBUG]:establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'port': 443, 'timeout'
: 70}
2015-07-30 19:14:14,171 foo [DEBUG]:Token: None
2015-07-30 19:14:14,171 foo [DEBUG]:StringToSign:
GET
```

The last part of the debugging output repeats a few times as the connection retries and then I get the socket.error. I'm very new to all things boto /s3 and quite new with python so apologies for any bad practices.

Is the issue with the proxy or something else?

Comment: Are you able to connect to s3.amazonaws.com on port 443 via your proxy?  If not then that is your problem.  For example:   >>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('https://s3.amazonaws.com')
>>> html = response.read()
>>> print(html)

Comment: Why don't you configure the proxy in boto config? It works flawlessly for me.

Comment: I was able to print off the html as above, but I'm still getting the same logging output and error - do I need to specify the port anywhere in that example? If the proxy isn't the connection issue, any idea what else may be causing it? How would I configure the proxy in the config and then call that out in the main script?